# SQL: Find rows with matching content (independant of column)

Tags: sql, join, pattern-matching, vertica

I have two tables in a vertica DB. First table has N+1 columns the second has N columns. I want to find the rows that have the same content but not necessary in the same order, to link the extra column to the second table. Here is an example for N=3:

Table1:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Value |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | C     |     3 |
| C     | D     | E     |     2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table2:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| C     | F     | E     |
| C     | A     | B     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see, in terms of row content the first row from Table1 is equal to the second row from Table2 just (expect the Value column) in a different order. So my question is: Is there a way to link both table in order to copy the Value to Table. To get the final Table.

TableF:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Value |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| C     | A     | B     |     3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Possible solution would be to order both table alphanumerical (Table1_sorted, Table2_sorted) like this:

```
SELECT T2.Item1, T2.Item2, T2.Item3, T1.Value 
FROM Table1_sorted T1, Table2_sorted T2 
WHERE T1.Item1=T2.Item1 AND T1.Item2 = T2.Item2 AND T1.Item3 = T2.Item3
```

However sorting alphanumerical is fairly complicated. Another way would be to use a bunch of `AND` `OR` combinations which is also not ideal. I was wondering if there is an easier solution.

Thanks!

Comment: is the number of columns fixed? or can N be greater than 3 shown in the example?

Comment: Ideally N would be greater than 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `UDx Scalar Function` that will check equality on row level. You can sort tuples or create set from tuples. I will show an example on Python, but highly recommended to write UDF on JAVA or C++.
(full demo on [youtube](https://youtu.be/qRtPp_-33KQ))

```
dbadmin=> select * from t1;
 item1 | item2 | item3 | value
-------+-------+-------+-------
 A     | B     | C     |     3
 C     | D     | E     |     2
(2 rows)

dbadmin=> select * from t2;
 item1 | item2 | item3
-------+-------+-------
 C     | A     | B
 C     | F     | E
(2 rows)

dbadmin=> select t1.* from t1, t2 where perm(t1.item1, t1.item2, t1.item3, t2.*);
 item1 | item2 | item3 | value
-------+-------+-------+-------
 A     | B     | C     |     3
(1 row)
```

if order of tuples is important:

```
dbadmin=> select t2.*, t1.value from t1, t2
dbadmin-> where perm(t1.item1, t1.item2, t1.item3, t2.*);
 item1 | item2 | item3 | value
-------+-------+-------+-------
 C     | A     | B     |     3
(1 row)
```

**For example on python** (for Vertica 8.x )

version 1:

```
def processBlock(self, server_interface, arg_reader, res_writer):
    while(True):
        cols = arg_reader.getNumCols()
        if cols % 2 != 0:
            raise ValueError("num of columns must be even")
        s1, s2 = set(), set()
        for i in range(cols):
            if i < cols / 2:
                s1.add(arg_reader.getString(i))
            else:
                s2.add(arg_reader.getString(i))
        res_writer.setBool(s1 == s2)
        res_writer.next()
        if not arg_reader.next():
            break
```

version 2:

```
def processBlock(self, server_interface, arg_reader, res_writer):
    while(True):
        cols = arg_reader.getNumCols()
        if cols % 2 != 0:
            raise ValueError("num of cols must be even")
        s = set()
        for i in range(cols):
            s.add(arg_reader.getString(i))
        res_writer.setBool(len(s) == cols / 2)
        res_writer.next()
        if not arg_reader.next():
            break
```

**Full code:**

```
import vertica_sdk

class perm(vertica_sdk.ScalarFunction):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setup(self, server_interface, col_types):
        pass

    def processBlock(self, server_interface, arg_reader, res_writer):
        #server_interface.log("log msg")
        while(True):
            # Example of error checking best practices.
            cols = arg_reader.getNumCols()
            if cols % 2 != 0:
                raise ValueError("num of cols must be even")
            s = set()
            for i in range(cols):
                s.add(arg_reader.getString(i))
            res_writer.setBool(len(s) == cols / 2)
            res_writer.next()
            if not arg_reader.next():
                break

    def destroy(self, server_interface, col_types):
        pass

class perm_factory(vertica_sdk.ScalarFunctionFactory):

    def createScalarFunction(self, srv):
        return perm()

    def getPrototype(self, srv_interface, arg_types, return_type):
        arg_types.addAny()
        return_type.addBool()

    def getReturnType(self, srv_interface, arg_types, return_type):
        return_type.addBool()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the Java version

```
+package com.iav.udsf.misc;
+
+import com.vertica.sdk.*;
+import java.io.PrintWriter;
+import java.io.StringWriter;
+import java.util.HashSet;
+import java.util.Set;
+
+/**
+ *
+ * @author gdpassar
+ */
+public class RowCompareFactory  extends ScalarFunctionFactory {
+
+    // Access to Vertica services (logging)
+    protected ServerInterface si;
+
+    /**
+     * Method called by Vertica in order to obtain the UDF interface (input and output parameters).
+     * Default is to have two input parameteres (a String representing the time intervals and a binary
+     * object containing the signal to analyse) and a String output parameter (representing a time
+     * interval, can be NULL if the UDF did not successfully apply to the given signal)
+     * @param srvInterface Vertica server interface
+     * @param argTypes Object for adding input parameters
+     * @param returnType Object for adding output parameters
+     */
+    @Override
+    public void getPrototype(ServerInterface srvInterface,
+                             ColumnTypes argTypes,
+                             ColumnTypes returnType)
+    {
+        argTypes.addAny();
+
+        returnType.addBool();
+    }
+
+    /**
+     * Method called by Vertica in order to obtain the return value type.
+     * @param srvInterface Vertica server interface
+     * @param argTypes Not used
+     * @param returnType Not used
+     */
+    @Override
+    public void getReturnType(ServerInterface srvInterface, SizedColumnTypes argTypes, SizedColumnTypes returnType) {
+        returnType.addBool();
+    }
+
+    /**
+     * UDF standard class, containing the parsing logic of the input parameters
+     */
+    public class udf extends ScalarFunction {
+
+        @Override
+        public void processBlock(ServerInterface srvInterface,
+                                 BlockReader argReader,
+                                 BlockWriter resWriter)
+                    throws UdfException, DestroyInvocation {
+            si = srvInterface;
+
+            do {
+                Set<Object> itemSet = new HashSet<>();
+                final int numCols = argReader.getNumCols();
+                if ((numCols % 2) != 0) {
+                    throw new UdfException(0, "Number of columns must be even");
+                }
+                try {
+                    itemSet.clear();
+                    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
+                        if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isVarchar()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getString(i));
+                        } else if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isInt()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getLong(i));
+                        } else if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isDate()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getDate(i));
+                        } else if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isFloat()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getDouble(i));
+                        } else if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isTimestamp()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getTimestamp(i));
+                        } else if (argReader.getTypeMetaData().getColumnType(i).isBool()) {
+                            itemSet.add(argReader.getBoolean(i));
+                        } else {
+                            throw new UdfException(0, "Data type not supported");
+                        }
+                    }
+                    
+                    resWriter.setBoolean(itemSet.size() == (numCols / 2));
+
+                } catch (Exception ex) {
+                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
+                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
+                    ex.printStackTrace(pw);
+                    si.log(sw.toString());
+                    resWriter.setBoolean(false);
+                }
+                resWriter.next();
+            } while (argReader.next());
+        }
+    }
+
+    /**
+     * Method called by Vertica in order to instantiate a new UDF when the query runs.
+     * @param srvInterface Vertica server interface
+     * @return Instance of a scalar function
+     */
+    @Override
+    public ScalarFunction createScalarFunction(ServerInterface srvInterface)
+    {
+        return new udf();
+    }
+}
```

Comment: Nice, it's much more better than `python`. As I said before my implementation  just a concept/example. Is it works for you?